# how to set destination to SendRawEmailRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

when I add single destination email it worked fine but when I am trying to add more email addresses to the collection it throws an exception
 `Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException: Local address contains illegal character (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:`

Here is my code

```
rawEmailRequest.setDestinations(Arrays.asList("To: some_email@hello.io",
                "CC: some_email@hello.io",
                "BCC: some_email@hello.io",
                "BCC: some_email@hello.io"));
```

Comment: did you see answer?
it was marked as accepted but I did not see any code related to my question

Comment: `setDestinations` only wants the addresses, no `TO: ` or anything before them.  The `To: ...`, etc. goes in the *headers* of the message you are building.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot can you give an example how to do it. thanks